# Cocoon JS and Kinetic JS

Tags: html, kineticjs, cocoonjs

I am developing an educational game for children (D&D, colors, shapes, numbers, etc) and I am using KineticJS for that purpose. It runs fine on Ipad 4 and Iphone 5, but on Android devices it runs with a very low framerate (Galaxy Tab 2 and Galaxy S2). I tried to compile the app with Cocoon JS to enable canvas acceleration, but it gets stuck on launch screeen (with phonegap build it runs fine).

Do I have to make any changes in the Kinetic source code to build on CocoonJS? Are there any alternatives to improve Kinetic performance on android devices?

Comment: have you tried to set your viewport to the following: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`? This makes a huge difference in performance if you scale your game up to `window.innerWidth`, because of the fact, that mobile browsers use a standard-viewport-width of 960px or so ;)

Comment: Hi! I change my viewport tag (`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>`) with yours, but the performance is the same on the galaxy tab.

Answer (score 0):

Cocoonjs cannot render the parent container (its a div). You need to overwrite the prototype of Kinetic.

```
Kinetic.Stage.prototype._buildDOM = function() {
this.content = this.attrs.container;
this.hitCanvas = new Kinetic.Canvas(0, 0, true);

this.bufferCanvas = new Kinetic.SceneCanvas({
    pixelRatio: 1
});

this.bufferHitCanvas = new Kinetic.HitCanvas();

this._resizeDOM();
```

};

Kinetic.Stage.prototype._getContentPosition = function() {
    var rect = this.content.getBoundingClientRect ? this.content.getBoundingClientRect() : { top : 0, left : 0 };
    return { top: rect.top, left: rect.left };
};

Then build your main stage as this.

this.stage = new Kinetic.Stage({width: 960, height: 500, container: document.body});